# Only 1 of 4 websites is accessible outside the network?

Tags: 18.04, apache2

I have 4 websites being hosted on same PC, this morning i figured out only one of them accessible externally. I mean, i can see for example www.rollpitch.com internally, but cannot see it on my mobile network. Only one of them is accessible (it is one of two which have SSL enabled, other one with SSL is not accessible as well).

I did reset ufw, switched off the router's firewall, nothing worked so far. I cannot come up with a reason why would only one work and others won't..

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

In the router both 80 and 443 is translated to 80 and 443(end). Also all sites are enabled in `apache2` (since i can see them within my local network). I don't know what further information to provide here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

http://rollpitch.com does not work, but https://rollpitch.com works. When you check from your phone you probably don't use https for three of the sites, but you do for the one that works.

The reason is simply that the web server doesn't appear to listen on port 80 (http), only 443 (https):

```
$ nmap -sV rollpitch.com
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-12-08 20:54 CET
Nmap scan report for rollpitch.com (95.70.136.144)
Host is up (0.076s latency).
rDNS record for 95.70.136.144: 144.136.70.95.dsl.dynamic.turk.net
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp  open   ssh     OpenSSH 7.6p1 Ubuntu 4ubuntu0.3 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
25/tcp  closed smtp
443/tcp open   ssl/ssl Apache httpd (SSL-only mode)
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 21.17 seconds
```

Best practice today would be to listen to both http and https, and redirect all clear text traffic to https.

Comment: Thanks for response vidarlo, I checked with `https://` and it really works, but I  `http://` is not being forwarded for some reason. But peytuk.com is working with both  `https://` and  `http://`. And two other sites (of which I cannot enable SSL, I need to create another topic for it) are not showing as well. Their config files are looking alright. I am so confused.

Comment: This is unfair, I deleted NAT rules, created same again and now it works.